# Перевод строки в массив цифр с помощью Stream API

Tags: java

На вход в метод будет приходить строка, эквивалентная по формату значению переменной `string`.
Как сделать Stream над переменной `string`, который сможет определять, является ли символ этой строки цифрой, и если да, то создавать массив `int[]` из этих цифр (каждая цифра - новый элемент `int[]` массива)? Чтобы в итоге можно было сделать `return` этого массива цифр.

Я написал код, который переводит строку в массив `int[]`, но мне нужно это сделать через Stream:

```
String string = "[1, 6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 2, 49, 54, 47]";
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(chars[i])) {
        integers.add(Character.getNumericValue(chars[i]));
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integers.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray()));
```

Comment: ваш код число 49 будет представлять как 2 разные цифры 4 и 9

Comment: Какой результат вы ожидаете в вашем примере?

Comment: ожидаю: return int[] {1, 6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 2, 49, 54, 47}

Comment: @KerLaeda как это "49"? Везде же (в коде и тексте вопроса) речь про "4" и "9". Как так-то?

Comment: Talex дал решение задачи. Спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Эквивалент вашего кода.

```
    String string = "[1, 6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 2, 49, 54, 47]";

    int[] ints = string.chars()
            .filter(Character::isDigit)
            .map(Character::getNumericValue)
            .toArray();
```

Но это скорее всего не то что вы хотите, `49` превратится в `4` и `9`.

Если хочется числа из строки то ответ:

```
    int[] ints = Stream.of(string.substring(1, string.length() - 1)
            .split(","))
            .map(String::trim)
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .toArray();
```

Comment: Ну тогда ок. Просто это как-то странно, возможно автор перепутал "цифра" и "число".

Comment: @Regent для некоторых `цифра ≡ число`, нередко попадаются вопросы типа найти сумму цифр цифры :)